Jupyter notebook is not rendering in github - Invalid json format
I want to know if theres an easy way to clean the jupyter notebook format by deleting that unnecesary lines of git control versions.
When running Jupyter notebook locally, I enncounter some versions problem with git, after fixed them the notebook is not rendering in github anymore, probably because when I solved the versions problem that add to the file lines like: <<<<<<<<HEAD, and that ruins the json format.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Do you have a public example you can share? It can be a toy example you make to parallel what you are actually using. I will say that you GitHub is unreliable and you should use the Jupyter Community's provided nbviewer. The GitHub one is just meant as a preview and lacks a lot of features. It sounds though like yours wouldn't work at nbviewer either but cannot tell without a shared example.

<<<<<HEAD means you're dealing with a file that is mid-merge, has merge conflicts, and requires your attention to fix. Use a code editor with git integration, a git UI application, or if you work with git every day, any random editor and the terminal to first properly fix your file by telling git which parts to keep and which parts to throw away.

This might help: How do I resolve merge conflicts in a Git repository?

This question is similar to: How do I resolve merge conflicts in a Git repository?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
